# How to set a particular encoding for stdin and stdout using open3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

Is it possible to set the encoding to utf-8 when sending input and capturing output via stdin and stdout respectively so that special characters like (™),à  etc can be preserved?

Here's my code(I am using windows i think the output has this encoding: IBM866 ):

```
require 'open3'
require 'pragmatic_segmenter' # just a gem that segments paragraphs to sentences

Open3.popen3("tagger") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thread|
  tokenized_group = Proc.new do |sentences|
    sentences_array = PragmaticSegmenter::Segmenter.new(text: sentences).segment

    sentences_array.map do |sentence|
      stdin.puts "#{sentence}" 
      stdout.gets.gsub(/\n$/,"").encode("utf-8") #=> is it possible to get this utf-8, right now its IBM866?
    end
  end

  puts tokenized_group.call "Some random sentence with ™. Another random sentence with à." 
  #output => Some/DT random/JJ sentence/NN with/IN тДв/NN ./. Another/DT random/JJ sentence/NN with/IN ├а/NN ./.

  stdin.close
end
```

As you can see the special characters are not preserved in the output because of different encoding. So, how can I get back the those characters in the stdout?

Comment: Why do you believe that the output has IBM866 encoding? What do `stdout.internal_encoding` and `.external_encoding` return? What is the encoding of the items in `sentences_array`? What are the actual byte values of the characters in question in the returned string?

Comment: @Jordan when i try to do string.match, it gives the error `incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with IBM866 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)`. `internal_encoding` returns nil, `external_encoding returns` IBM866. For ™(returns тДв), its `[209, 130, 208, 148, 208, 178]` for à(returns ├а) its `[226, 148, 156, 208, 176]`

Answer (score 3):

This is an odd little problem. I *think* this will work:

```
stdout.gets.encode(Encoding::IBM866, Encoding::UTF_8)
```

This tells `encode` both the source and destination encoding. Note that you need to do this *before* calling `gsub` or any other regex method on the string.

You may be able to skip this by instead using [`set_encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-set_encoding) to tell the `stdout` object to do the conversion for you:

```
stdout.set_encoding(Encoding::IBM866, Encoding::UTF_8)
```

Do that the first thing in your `popen3` block.

For what it's worth, here's the code I used to test this:

```
# ™(returns тДв)
a = [209, 130, 208, 148, 208, 178] 

# à(returns ├а)
b = [226, 148, 156, 208, 176]

a_str = a.pack("c*")
puts a_str.encode(Encoding::IBM866, Encoding::UTF_8)
# => ™

b_str = b.pack("c*")
puts b_str.encode(Encoding::IBM866, Encoding::UTF_8)
# => à
```

Comment: just tried but the first one gives `U+00E9 from UTF-8 to IBM866 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)` the second one(ie setting encoding right under open block start) didn't give an error but it gave the same incorrect character.